# MySQL query only returning COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

On my site I am executing an SQL query to fill information. The section of code doing so is this:

```
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string(db_connect(),$_SESSION['UserName']);
$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE username='{$user}'";
$out = mysqli_query(db_connect(), $sqlStr);

$settings = False;
if(!(0 == mysqli_num_rows($out))){
    $settings = True;
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($out);
}
```

Which should only return one row for a given user. However, the output is extremely funky. For a given user who has an entry in the database, the output is as follows:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => x [lengths] => Array ( [x] => x ) [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

This is correct, but then when mysqli_fetch_assoc is performed, the result is this:

```
Array ( [COUNT] => 2 )
```

I am completely failing to understand how it is returning a COUNT at all, let alone 2 rows. There isn't even 2 rows in the database. This happens for any username.

Comment: If no connection is open, mysqli_real_escape_string() will return an empty string. It appears to me that you're connecting with db_connect() after using the string escape function. This could be buggering it up for you, but either way something should be changed. I recommend pdo if it works for your project scope.

Comment: Also, worth using strict comparisons wherever you can `===`. Also in PHP booleans are lowercase `true`, `false`, not `True`, `False` as those are aliased (but that's me being picky).

Comment: Sorry, I should have included an example SQL string. The output is correct, without an empty escaped string. The query executes properly in Workbench and returns the correct values. The issue occurs for some reason between that step and the fetching of the values, as shown by the print_f outputs.

Comment: Can you make it into a minimal example, so `$sqlStr = "full string"; $out = ....; var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($out));`

Comment: Sorry, let me check, you want the var_dump on the fetch, and the SQL string doing the query?

Comment: Just make it as simple as possible, as you remove things it will likely be fixed or you're narrowed down what the cause could be to one or two lines

Answer (score 0):

A workaround has been found. The output is iterated through with a while() loop beforehand. The following is the working code:

```
$settings = False;
If(!(0 == mysqli_num_rows($out))){
    $settings = True;
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($out)){
        $var = $res['var'];

        break;
    }
}
```

and then using $var throughout the site instead of $res['var']. This properly fills the information. This fixes the issue, though I still don't understand what was causing the issue in the first place.